# When switching tty, who is responsible for synchronizing the state of keyboard NumLock?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, tty, numlock, capslock

My Xorg program uses `tty1`. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[2~6]</kbd> to switch between `ttY[2~6]`. At this time, the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> or <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> state (including the corresponding LED light on the keyboard) can be synchronized normally.

If I switch between `tty1` and `tty[2~6]`, the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> or <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> state is normal, but the keyboard light does not switch normally. I want to know, who is responsible for saving and switching the <kbd>NumLock</kbd> or <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> state of the `tty` keyboard (including the corresponding LED light on the keyboard)?

Use `evtest` to monitor keyboard events, an example is as follows:

scene 1:

```
tty1: Num led is on, you can input numbers;
tty2: Num Led is off, you cannot enter numbers;
tty1-->tty2: Num led is on, no number can be input

ctrl+alt+f2, tty1-->tty2, evtest print as follows:

Event: time 1631671173.524324, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1631671173.524324, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1631671173.524324, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1631671173.612530, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e2
Event: time 1631671173.612530, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT), value 1
Event: time 1631671173.612530, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1631671173.684525, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7003b
Event: time 1631671173.684525, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 60 (KEY_F2), value 1
Event: time 1631671173.684525, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1631671173.804507, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1631671173.804507, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 0
Event: time 1631671173.804507, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1631671173.812235, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e2
Event: time 1631671173.812235, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT), value 0
Event: time 1631671173.812235, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1631671173.824310, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7003b
Event: time 1631671173.824310, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 60 (KEY_F2), value 0
Event: time 1631671173.824310, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

scene 2:

```
tty2: Num led is on, you can input numbers;
tty3: Num Led is off, you cannot enter numbers;
tty2-->tty3: Num led is off, no number can be input

ctrl+alt+f3, tty2-->tty3, evtest print as follows:

Event: time 1631671357.985873, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1631671357.985873, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 1
Event: time 1631671357.985873, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1631671358.097893, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e2
Event: time 1631671358.097893, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT), value 1
Event: time 1631671358.097893, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1631671358.181861, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7003c
Event: time 1631671358.181861, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 61 (KEY_F3), value 1
Event: time 1631671358.181861, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1631671358.313866, type 17 (EV_LED), code 0 (LED_NUML), value 0
Event: time 1631671358.313866, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7003c
Event: time 1631671358.313866, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 61 (KEY_F3), value 0
Event: time 1631671358.313866, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1631671358.321862, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e0
Event: time 1631671358.321862, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 29 (KEY_LEFTCTRL), value 0
Event: time 1631671358.321862, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1631671358.337870, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 700e2
Event: time 1631671358.337870, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 56 (KEY_LEFTALT), value 0
Event: time 1631671358.337870, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```